# How to show a history of executed tmux commands?

Tags: tmux

> How to show a history of executed tmux commands?

Sometimes I unintentionally  execute some `tmux` command through a key binding, like selecting a window in another `tmux` session, and I would like to see exactly what happened.

Does `tmux` support a history of executed commands, either directly through `C-a :` or through key bindings, like `bash`'s `history` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is a history of everything you recently typed at the `:` prompt (you can see it either by scrolling at the prompt with the `Up` and `Down` keys, or by setting the `history-file` option). There is no overall history of every command that has been run.

Comment: Thank you, @NicholasMarriott. What about commands executed through key bindings?

Comment: There is no history of these.

Comment: That's a shame. I would count those as "executed commands" also, although not executed directly through `C-a :`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know why executing `set -g history-file ~/.tmux_history` doesn't list the option in `show -g`?

Comment: It is a server option, so `show -s`.

Comment: Just to be sure, will `tmux` only write to `history-file`, when all sessions exit? Currently, when I exit panes or windows, the file is not being written to.

Comment: Hmm good point actually, it does only write it on shutdown. Sorry, I thought it was written all the time.

Comment: I had thought of logging all commands, maybe to the message buffer (`C-b ~`) which is currently underused. But it seems like it'd get flooded with commands very quickly.

Comment: Also, `history-file` only seems to support up to 100 lines? I could not find an option for increasing this in `man tmux`. `set -s message-limit 1000` didn't affect the history limit.

Comment: Yeah it is pretty limited. I don't think many people use it.

Comment: The problem with writing them to the message buffer is that it is per-client so they would be lost when the client is detached. But if you only want a reference of what you did in the last few minutes, then that would work.

Comment: You can try this diff against master if you like to write each command to the client message buffer: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nicm/b067d458a3ac3b00f125aa39cb33c956/raw/fe565d2b270206af302fb2627fc1da0141922b05/gistfile1.txt But I am not going to add this as-is, I think I will do it but change so the message buffer is global and a bit more useful.

Comment: If you build tmux from Git master now, the `C-b ~` message log does includes every command run. This will be in tmux 3.2.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Does that include commands run by key bindings also?

Comment: Yes all commands except those in the config file.